# Is it legal to construct std::string_view from empty vector<char>?

Tags: c++, c++20, string-view

I have read some questions and [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data), and I guess answer is yes, since `string_view` will never touch the pointed to stuff, but I am a still bit confused if this is legal:

```
std::vector<char> v;
std::string_view sv(v.data(), v.size());
```

note:

1. I know that constructor that just uses `v.data()` and does `strlen`
   will crash, I am asking about this particular way of constructing
   `std::string_view`.
2. I know that constructed `string_view` is "evil", e.g. doing `std::cout << sv.data()` is UB, but I think `std::cout << sv;` should work

Full example:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <string_view>

std::vector<char> v;
auto get_sv() {
std::string_view sv(v.data(), v.size());
return sv;
} 

int main() {
    std::cout << "|" << get_sv() << "|" << std::endl;

}
```

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view/basic_string_view, I'd say this is the third constructor. There, it says the "behavior is undefined if [s, s+count) is not a valid range". `[nullptr, nullptr+0]` is a valid, albeit empty range. I think.

Comment: `strlen` requires a pointer to a null terminated string, which an empty `v` is not, which is why it crashes. Null terminated strings are a concept inherited from C but in general C++ features don't care if they can help it. By providing `v.size()` the `string_view` constructor doesn't care if the string is null terminated or not.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt `data()` isn't guaranteed to be `nullptr` for an empty container, but `data()` guarantees that the range `[v.data(); v.data() + v.size())` is a valid range even if the size is zero.

Comment: Doing `std::cout << sv.data()` is always a bad idea, at least semantically. It relies on null-termination, which `std::string_view` itself never provides.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks perfectly legal to me.

According to [`basic_string_view( const CharT* s, size_type count );`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view/basic_string_view)

> 3. Constructs a view of the first count characters of the character array starting with the element pointed by s.

and [`std::vector::data()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data) states:

> Returns pointer to the underlying array serving as element storage. The pointer is such that range [data(); data() + size()) is always a valid range, even if the container is empty (data() is not dereferenceable in that case).

and

> **Notes**
> If size() is 0, data() may or may not return a null pointer.

So depending on the implementation, the underlying char array exists at the time of printing, or the `string_view` was built with a `nullptr`. In either case it is a valid range.